# json_decode with values containing double quotes

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, double-quotes

I am trying to use an editable table and have it working except for when the array values passed to the save function contain double quotes.  The error occurs at foreach loop

```
foreach($saveArray as $rowId=>$row) {
```

It is the values (not keys) which may contain double quotes, the actual error being:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

What is the best way around this, some way to escape them, change them to the &quot code, change the way the loop works?

EDIT:

Sorry, the problem is actually with the json_decode function and double quote values, not returning an array.

Works fine for non double quoted entries

json looks like

`{"2":{"component":"8\"", ...`

So it is escaped but it's not decoding into an array

Comment: Are you sure `$saveArray` is an array in your code?

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` means `$saveArray` is *not an array*. Show us a `var_dump` of `$saveArray`.

Comment: in that case the fault is occuring with the json_decode function, for the same reason (double-quotes), everything works fine for entries without double quotes

Comment: In that case we need more information about your problem/code...

Comment: I have edited the question, json_decode does not return an array when a double quote exists

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode('{"2":{"bar":"foo\""}}', true))` > `array(1) { [2]=> array(1) { ["bar"]=> string(3) "foo"" } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what `$saveArray` actually is, using

```
var_dump($saveArray)
```

It doesn't look like your `$saveArray`, whatever it is, supports the `foreach` construct.

If `$saveArray` comes from `json_decode()`, it's likely that your JSON string is invalid, and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) just returns `NULL`.

Comment: That is what is happening, I have edited the question.  Is there a valid way to place a double quote in a json string?

Comment: Mattp: The same way you place a double-quote into a double-quoted Javascript string... escape it. But don't forget that those escapes will be removed, one at a time, by each layer of processing that the string goes through.

Comment: Found the issue, the code was using the stripslashes function on the json string, i'll change it for my own function